# Setting table with object in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an object I want to put in a table.
the object seems like: `{"text":"111","order":["1","2","3","4","5"]}`
there may be array as well as simple strings.
So how can I put this object in a table if I want the table to look like this:

```
property   value
text       111
order      1,2,3,4,5
```

My table shows in the value column `["1","2","3","4","5"]` instead of `1,2,3,4,5`.

Here is what I wrote:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="(key,val) in object">
    <td>
        {{ key }}
    </td>   
    <td>
        {{val}}
    </td>        
</tr>
```

I also tried with `ng-swtich` but it didn't work.

Comment: You could check if the val is an Array and join them..

Comment: Can you post more of your relevant code? At least the controller for your app?

Comment: @Karthik how can I check if its an array and join them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample which checks if the value is an Array and joins them as a string.

Html:

```
 <tr data-ng-repeat="(key,val) in object">
    <td>
        {{ key }}
    </td>   
    <td>
        {{val | isArray}}
    </td>        
  </tr>
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.object = {"text":"111","order":["1","2","3","4","5"]};
});

app.filter("isArray", function() {
      return function(input) {
        var isArray = angular.isArray(input);
        if(isArray)
          return input.join();
        return input;
      };
});
```

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/OLE2Vsqh6WLWkbrafrMA?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you were after?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<table ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyTableController">
  <tr data-ng-repeat="(key,val) in data">
    <td>
      {{ key }}
    </td>

    <td >
      {{ val | join: ', ' }}
    </td>        
  </tr>
</table>

<script>
angular.module('app', [])
  // Filter that joins the input with the supplied separator
  .filter('join', function () {
    return function (value, separator) {
      if (typeof value.join === 'function') {
        return value.join(separator);
      } else {
        return value;
      }
    }
  })
  .controller('MyTableController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.data = {"text":"111","order":["1","2","3","4","5"] };
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is what i'm looking for. unfortunately I cant accept 2 answers